# how to Pass the IBMMQ Queue/Topic name dynamically in JMS Admin

Tags: ibm-mq, jms-topic

I wanted to pass the queue or topic name dynamically inside the jms admin. any help is appreciated.

below is the what i am trying

```
    export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mqm/lib64
mkdir /tmp/jndi
cd /tmp
echo $'INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory\n
PROVIDER_URL=file:///tmp/jndi\n
SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION=none' > JMSAdmin.config
chmod -R 4777 /opt/mqm/java
cp /tmp/JMSAdmin.config /opt/mqm/java/bin/
cd /opt/mqm/java/bin/
./JMSAdmin
DEFINE QCF(mqqcf) QMGR(QM1) tran(client) chan(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) host(localhost) port(1415)
DEFINE Q($queueName) QUEUE($queueName) QMGR(QM1)
```

$queueName is what i am looking to pass dynamically

Comment: How about: `printf "DEFINE QCF(mqqcf) QMGR(QM1) tran(client) chan(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) host(localhost) port(1415)\nDEFINE Q($queueName) QUEUE($queueName) QMGR(QM1)\n"|./JMSAdmin`

Comment: thanks JoshMC, I will try and update here